# ajax - starting and ending sessions with onload and onunload

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a signup page.

On this page, user input values are checked asynchronously by a php backend against tables.

My problem is that data model objects are fairly large; would it be wise to start a session via ajax when someone enters the page (onload), which caches the model objects so that all other ajax requests from that client don't end up recreating the data model objects every request. Then when the user navigates away from the page (onunload or whatever) an ajax request is send the destroy the session.

It seems a good idea to me because every asynchronous request made as a result of a user interaction with the form doesn't recreate all the objects that have been created before hand.

Would this work in practice?

(for details of my worries see comments)

UPDATE:

The main issue raised is that it will create a dangling session. Could this be fixed by putting just a simple 5 minute timeout on the session?

Comment: Sounds like a pretty good idea. Why do you think it *won't* work?

Comment: I spose my worry is that I don't know if this a widely adopted practice, and if its not then I'm worried that therre is a good reason for it not being widely adopted.. if that makes sense:S

Comment: For example a well known inconsistency with onunload that I'm unaware of, that might cause a broken session or something

Comment: If you cannot *share* session between users, you may end up using a lot of resources with just a few users. Nothing else comes to mind.

Comment: I think if the client closes the page, you can't really tell if they closed it. (Unless you're polling or using sockets)

Comment: I believe it would create a dangling session, that'll remain in memory for no reason. Maybe you should have a scheduled task that checks and clears all session not used within the last X minutes (and for that you'll need to keep track of when a session was last used). Yeah, i guess it too much to bother. Maybe you shouldn't do this! :-)

Comment: What about just putting a shorter timeout on the session? LIke a 5 minute timeout, Ive got a live search in there which requests onkeyup so there will be probably be lots a requests sent per minute, depending on how fast they can type.

Comment: ^ I like that idea. -- and of course if someone sends another request, it would bump their time back to 5 minutes.

Comment: That should be fine right aslong as it eventually times out..? Another point is that the idea of the sign up page is to get people to sign up and continue as a user, so this would mean that all the objects created can be reused in their potential user session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wondering, this proved to be an unbearably horrible idea. it was alright in principle but managing all the sessions and making sure everything stays synchronous with the front end was near impossible and in no way scalable, which in turn made my controller structure so complicated that it was a nightmare to debug (not to mention I had to clear my browser cache every time I updated the development repo.. ). it managed to wasted a lot of my time and caused me to miss some crucial deadlines and ultimately was a massive effort for what was really a tiny overhead.

Please don't try this.